# In except, capturing a simple linux command into a variable

Tags: bash, expect

What is the expect equivalent of this bash command?

```
host=`hostname`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since expect is build  on top of Tcl, you have all Tcl's commands at your disposal:

```
set host [info hostname]
```